# This Bind Function... and these arguments, and this apply method... I'm not sure I understand how this is working in this example

Tags: javascript

taken from http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#84

```
function bind(context, name){ 
  return function(){ 
    return context[name].apply(context, arguments); 
  }; 
}
```

I'm really trying to get how this works. This function works, however, if you console.log arguments from the innermost function, they are not there.  So how can they possibly be used in the apply function that they are called with?

In other words:

```
function bind(context, name){ 
  console.log(arguments.length === 2, true);
  return function(){ 
    console.log(arguments.length === 0, true);
    return context[name].apply(context, arguments); 
  }; 
}
```

You can console.log the arguments in the outer function and get the length property.  But from that innermost function, the arguments.length === 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the closure for now to simplify.

The function `bind` returns a function like:

```
function returnedFunction() {
    return context[name].apply(context, arguments);
}
```

So if I call `returnedFunction(1,2,3);` the arguments are `1, 2, 3`. If I call `returnedFunction()` there is no arguments.

Now we have to worry about `context` and `name` which would be `undefined` in the simplification, that's when you look at the closure and see they are defined in the outer function.

`arguments` and `this` are not variables so they cannot be closed over. They are evaluated for every function call separately. They are evaluated for the `bind` for whatever arguments you pass to `bind`, and then they are evaluated for the `returnedFunction` each time you call `returnedFunction`.

Note that functions returned from `bind` have no relation to each other. They each have their own unique environment with different `context` and `name` bindings.

Comment: `arguments` and `this` are not variables so they cannot be closed over. They are evaluated for every function call separately. That sentence right there really helps me get it. Thank you, much appreciated, it's been bugging me for a while.